# Export to Excel with Hyperlink in a cell to another worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, hyperlink, office-interop

I'm exporting data into excel file,I'm trying to create a hyperlink in a specific cell which should navigate to worksheet.
Hyper link is getting created, issue is when i click the hyperlink it is not navigating to the specified worksheet.
For instance:
My Code-

```
string Address = StringConstants.worksheet_Name + "!A1";

Excel.Hyperlink hyperlink = (Excel.Hyperlink)worksheet.Hyperlinks.Add(worksheet.get_Range("D5", 
                               Type.Missing),  Address, string.Empty, "Go to", TextToDisplay);
```

Error Thrown when I click the Hyperlink:

> **Cannot open specified file**

Answer (score 0):

You should use parameter [Subaddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlink.subaddress) as a location within workbook and leave the [Address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlink.address) blank, if the hyperlink targets its own workbook. In your snippet just swap the parameters and it should work fine:

```
var Subaddress = StringConstants.worksheet_Name + "!A1";
Excel.Hyperlink hyperlink = (Excel.Hyperlink)worksheet.Hyperlinks.Add(worksheet.Range["D5"],
  string.Empty, Subaddress, "Go to", TextToDisplay);
```

Address should be used when:

- targeting another workbook
- targeting a file or website
- creating a "mailto" link

Comment: Thanks, peter! I have tried the same, now its saying "Reference isn't valid"

Comment: @sherlin What exactly is the content of `StringConstants.worksheet_Name`? If the worksheet name includes spaces, then [it must be enclosed in single quotes](https://superuser.com/questions/946849/how-do-i-reference-an-excel-sheet-name-in-an-excel-formula).

Comment: @sherlin You're welcome! Accepting and/or upvoting the answer is the way to thank here at *stackoverflow* ;).